# R in Sublime Text 3 using SublimeREPL, shortcut issue

Tags: r, shortcut

I've been struggling alone to fix this problem but I give up.
Here is what's happening: I'm using the statistical R language in Sublime Text 3. On one page I code and I use the following shortcuts to send the code to the R console in ST3, ( all of this using SublimeREPL):

```
{"word_separators": "/\\()\"‘-:,;~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"},

{ "keys": ["alt+shift+r"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "selection"}},

{ "keys": ["f2"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "file"}}, 

{ "keys": ["alt+r"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "lines"}},

{ "keys": ["shift+alt+r"], "command": "repl_transfer_current", "args": {"scope": "block"}}
```

They all work fine, or almost, because they send the data to the R-console but nothing appears in the R-console except an extra ">".
Here is an example,
My script:

```
test <- c(1,2)
ls()
test
```

In the R-console:

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) -- "Warm Puppy"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R est un logiciel libre livré sans AUCUNE GARANTIE.
Vous pouvez le redistribuer sous certaines conditions.
Tapez 'license()' ou 'licence()' pour plus de détails.

R est un projet collaboratif avec de nombreux contributeurs.
Tapez 'contributors()' pour plus d'information et
'citation()' pour la façon de le citer dans les publications.

Tapez 'demo()' pour des démonstrations, 'help()' pour l'aide
en ligne ou 'help.start()' pour obtenir l'aide au format HTML.
Tapez 'q()' pour quitter R.

> > [1] "test"
> [1] 1 2
>
```

What should be in the console using alt+r for every line:

```
> test <- c(1,2)
> ls()
> [1] "test"
> test
> [1] 1 2
```

Also if I use "arrow up" to get the last line of code which was entered, nothing displays if I sent it from the scrip.

Details that might be useful: I use Windows 7 64b, I had to edit the R path in order to make  SublimeREPL work.

This may be a very stupid question but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks a lot in advance if you can help

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences/Packages Settings/Sublime-REPL/Settings-User and add

```
{
"show_transferred_text": true
}
```

This is by defaults on macs, not on computers running windows, it seems.